# How can I integrate Xamarin Forms new shell with Prism?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

is there any way how to integrate Xamarin Forms new Shell with Prism?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can judge Xamarin Shell is not yet 100% ready to be customized / extensible for 3rd part frameworks like Prism.

One of the missing things for example is a [handler](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5166) for shell navigation, which will be needed for view model conventions and dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

I've read the Prism documentation which clearly states that it's not working great yet.
You can add the nuget project but navigation won't work (IInitialize, IInitializeAsync, INavigatedAware, IConfirmNavigation, IConfirmNavigationAsync). You will still get other things like command, etc.

Answer (score -3):

go to the nuget package manager and update your xamarin.forms to 4 and greater